# Good approach to autosizing buttons to match graphic designer's intent in Swift/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, autoresize

I am trying to match my graphic designer's interface design to be exact in every IOS device. My problem is the images on the buttons are never the right ratio and I am having trouble making sure the buttons autosize correctly. 
[This is a picture of the artist's intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruCKK.jpg)

[This is my implementation of the buttons using different views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxjyd.png)

How do I resolve these autosizing issues to correctly solve this problem? I have watched plenty of tutorials on resizing images, but I haven't seen any that cover images that aren't symmetrical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply wish to resize those "buttons" (which I assume are actually UIImageViews) depending upon the device, create a relational constraint between the button image and the parent views (in your case, I suppose these should be the black and white UIViews). You can accomplish this by tapping both of the views at the same time and then "Create width/ height constraint".

Then, select the constraint and tap the "Show Utilities Area" (the most top right corner button). You'll have there in the Attributes a `Multiplication` property. The default is 1. Keep in mind that if the first element of the relational constraint is the parent view, then the multiplication factor has to be lower than 1 and viceversa.

EG: I suppose your button should always have a 1/6 part of the screen. Then, you should write in the `Multiplication` property of your constraint either `1/6` or `0.17`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I almost have it thanks to your advice. So would you recommend using UIImageView instead of a UIButton with an image?

Comment: Not necessarly. I simply supposed those are UIImageViews, but there's nothing wrong with having them as UIButtons. It's easier to add the touch `@IBOutlets`, so that sounds good for you if you wish to add some behaviour (even if it's not the only way, check out `UITapGestureRecognizer`).

Comment: The UIImageView definitely works much better for resizing! Do you typically use a UIImage View and put a button on top of it?

Comment: No, for clicks on UIImageView I use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Glad I could help you!

Comment: Works perfectly I'll post the resolution.

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting the answer if this was the solution or led you there? :)

Comment: Sure! I am new to stack exchange what do I need to do to give you credit or say this was resolved? Anything you want Razvan! I need one more like before I can share my resolution because it won't let me post another link till I have 15 points.

Comment: Thank you! Oh, and yes, indeed you need 15 points for that. But, meanwhile, I think they let you tap the award answer button? It's just below the down arrow, in the left part of the answer.

Comment: Cool, I awarded you the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, Anytime!!